# Storing individual elements in a list as seperate variables python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list say for example , a =["1","2"]

i want , c =1 and d = 2 . I can do c = a[0] , d = a[1] which will give me the required output , but if the list contents are dynamic ? How to store each elements in a list in a variable.

Thanks

Comment: You can't create variables on the fly like that. In order to do what you want, you need another list, just to hold those values.. But then why not just keep and use the original list?

Comment: Yes, i could achieve what i was trying to do with the original list itself. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Comment: `c, d = seq` is a shorthand unpacking form, but it won't help you with 'dynamic' list length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (bad practice, but works):

```
x = ord('a')
list = ["1", "2"]
for i in list:
    exec('%s="%s"' % (chr(x), i))
    x+=1
```

But I would personally go this way:

```
from collections import namedtuple

list = ["1", "2"]
names = ["a", "b"]
d = dict(zip(names,list))
obj = namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
```

Then, you can use `obj.a`, `obj.b`, etc.